# How to save sqlalchemydiff results to file?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm developing too to compare database schema of Test and Prod database.
I can succesfully compare schema and print to command line.

However I don't know how to store results to JSON, CSV file or any file. Please advice!

```
from pprint import pprint
from sqlalchemydiff import compare
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
import pyodbc
import time

# Pass through Pyodbc string
conn_string_dw_test = "DRIVER=..."
conn_string_dw_prod = "DRIVER=..."

connection_url_dw_test = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": conn_string_dw_test})
connection_url_dw_prod = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": conn_string_dw_prod})

print('')
print('-----SCHEMA COMPARE FOR TEST AND PROD DW-----')
result_dw = compare(connection_url_dw_test, connection_url_dw_prod)

if result_dw.is_match:
    print('')
    print('DW Schemas are identical')
    print('')
else:
    print('')
    print('We detected following differences')
    print('DW Test is on Left. DW Prod is on Right')
    print('')
pprint(result_dw.errors)

# Export CSV
filename = "SchemaCompareReports\SchemaCompareReport_" +  time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + ".csv"
result_dw.to_csv(filename)  # NOT WORKING
print("Report exported: " + filename)
```

1. ERROR in first try:

   traceback (most recent call last):
   File ".\SchemaComparePOC.py", line 74, in 
   result_dw.to_csv(filename)
   AttributeError: 'CompareResult' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
2. I also tried in second try to save results to json file, but got error:

   filename = "SchemaCompareReport_DW_" +  time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + ".json"
   a_file = open(filename, "w")
   json.dump(result_dw.dump_errors, a_file)
   a_file.close()

Error of second try:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./SchemaComparePOC.py", line 106, in <module>
    json.dump(result_dw.dump_errors, a_file)
  File "C:\Python\Python3.8.9\lib\json\__init__.py", line 179, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "C:\Python\Python3.8.9\lib\json\encoder.py", line 438, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "C:\Python\Python3.8.9\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type method is not JSON serializable
```

3. In third try I got no error, but file was empty:

   ```
   filename = "SchemaCompareReport" +  time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + ".json"
    a_file = open(filename, "w")
    json.dump(result_dw.dump_errors.__dict__, a_file)
    a_file.close()
   ```

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://sqlalchemy-diff.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#), `errors` is a hierarchical structure, so it doesn't map directly to csv.  There are a lot of Q&As here about mapping JSON structures to csv   which should help you to work with this.

Comment: Also from the docs: "If you wish to persist that dict to a JSON file, you can quickly do so by calling `result.dump_errors()`"

Comment: What is syntax for saving as CSV with result.dump_errors()

Comment: result_dw.dump_errors did not work yet. Please see updated questions.

Comment: result_dw.dump_errors()
#TypeError: Object of type immutabledict is not JSON serializable